Is it possible to create a reusable function in Reactjs
I would like to create a reusable function in a standalone JavaScript file that I could use to send two parameters in the form of a json to an API, using the GET method, which would return a json file that I could use in my home.js file. I'm thinking this can be done, but not sure how or if their is a better way.  I would love to know what the best practice is in Reactjs to do this is.
This is the request json:
{ "exam_id": 1, "question_id": 22 }

This the expected returned json:
[
    {
        "Choice_1": "choice 1",
        "Choice_2": "choice 2",
        "Choice_3": "choice 3",
        "Choice_4": "choice 4",
        "Choice_5": "choice 5",
        "Question": "This field represents the question to be asked.",
        "QuestionID": 22,
        "Scenario": "something needed to expand on the question asked.",
        "Answer": "correct answer for question."
    }
]

My current working environment and versions:

windows OS
MS VSCode IDE
react: 18.3.1
npm: 10.8.0
npx: 10.8.0

I've created the following but it is not working yet.
Which is why I am here asking questions.
file name: Question.js
contents:
import React from 'react';

function GetQuestion() {
    
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const request_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/exam/question';
        const request_json= '{"exam_id": '+{exam_id}+', "question_id": '+{question_id}+'}';
        const request={request_url} + '?' + {request_json};
        const response = await fetch(request);
        const response_data = await response.json();
        setData(response_data);
    };

    return fetchData()
}

export default GetQuestion;


Pass the setData to the fetchData function, then fetchData can simply update a dynamically stored "data" variable. Your approach to including json data in the request is poorly formed as well, that'd work for GET parameters but just about nothing else. You'd also need to pass the details particular to the request itself (e.g. question_id and exam_id), which starts to make this method almost abstract enough to be useless (vs. just writing this code to begin with).

This looks like the same conversation from your previous question.  The format of the request you're making is highly unusual and very likely to be wrong.  (At the very least the string concatenation isn't going to produce the result you're expecting.)  But more to the point... In what specific way does this fail?  When you test it, in your browser's debugging tools, what are the details of the AJAX request being made?  Does it differ from what you expect?  What is the server's response?  Does it differ from what you expect?

At a glance the immediate problem is the string concatenation.  Don't surround the values with curly braces.  That makes them objects instead of values, and the string representation of an object isn't going to be valid JSON or in any way meaningful.  But aside from that, this is still very likely to "not work" because of several other potential problems.  Before you make any request to the server, you need to know how the server expects to receive the data.  Can you provide that in the question?

@Rogue - Thank you for some good suggestions, I will try these and get back to you on the results.

Is your goal to use the result in a component? If so could you please show the component that you would like displaying the data? Also another solution could simply be to return the response_data from your function, and wrap the fetchData() by your setData function you are using in your component, so it would looke something like this.
`
const [data, setData] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
const newData = await fetchData();
setData(newData);
}, [];
`
Let me know if you still need help.

So it's hard to know exactly your question when you dont show the component itself. here is an example of using hooks to make a request. In this example i have 2 hooks, one that makes a fetch request on initial render and the other based on the change of a state variable (in your case it would be the form)
app.tsx
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useGetPlanets } from "./useGetPlanets";
import { useGetDataFromUrl } from "./useGetDataFromUrl";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedPlanet, setSelectedPlanet] = useState<Record<string, any>>({});

  // Both hooks must remain consistently triggered on all renders. meaning between update of state both hooks must be triggered. you can pass in state to avoid over fetching

  const planetsData = useGetPlanets();
  const selectedPlanetData = useGetDataFromUrl(selectedPlanet?.url);

  return (
    <main>
      <h3>{selectedPlanetData?.name}</h3>
      <ul>
        {planetsData.map((planet: any, i: number) => {
          return (
            <li
              key={planet.name + i}
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              onClick={() => setSelectedPlanet(planet)}
            >
              {planet.name}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </main>
  );
}


useGetPlanets.ts
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useGetPlanets = () => {
  const [planetsData, setPlanetsData] = useState([]);
  const fetchPlanets = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/planets/", {
      method: "GET",
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    setPlanetsData(data?.results);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPlanets();
  }, []);

  return planetsData;
};

useGetDataFromUrl.ts
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useGetDataFromUrl = (url: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Record<string, any>>({});
  const fetchDataByUrl = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
      });
      if (!res.ok) throw new Error("Fetch Error!");
      const data = await res.json();

      setData(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error:", err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDataByUrl();
  }, [url]);

  return data;
};

i would NOT recommend this approach in an application so superficially constructed as it will trigger the fetch on every re-render. put in conditions to prevent this. but hopefully this puts you on the right track as to re-using async/await and state in hook
